# Query MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
    {
        "_id" : {
            "processUuid" : "653d0937-2afc-4915-ad42-d2b69f344402",
            "partnerId" : "p377"
        },
        "isComplete" : true,
        "tasks" : {
            "dbb361a7-4b73-4691-bde5-2b160346464f" : {
                "sku" : "4060079000048",
                "status" : "FAILED",
                "errorList" : [....]
            },
            "790dbc6f-563d-4eb7-931c-3cc604563dc1" : {
                "sku" : "4060079000130",
                "status" : "SUCCESSFUL",
                "errorList" : [....]
            },
            ... more tasks
        }
        ... more processes
    }
```

I want to query a certain sku and couldnt find a way. I know i could write an aggregation pipeline to project the inner part of a task, but then i would lose the task identifier which i need in order to add some stuff to a task. 
I know the document structure is weird, i would have done it different, but its given.
I tried what i found about querying nested documents and so on, but unfortunately didnt get it. Any hints  are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347376/how-to-find-specific-nested-objects-without-knowing-the-parent-key-in-mongodb) answer your query?

Comment: Yes! This looks great, the key is obviously to find a way to transform the tasks in an array to be able to perform array queries. Thanks a lot!