# MongoDB find by object key

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following structure (swagger file):

```
{
    "swagger":"2.0",
    ...
    "paths": {
        "/pet": {
            "post" : { ... }
            "put" : { ... }
         },
         "/anotherpetstore": {
            "post" : { ... }
            "put" : { ... }
         }
    }
}
```

I now want to have something like {'paths': {'$regex':'pet'}} and find both paths.

Is that even possible in MongoDB?

I found some similar questions which never looked for the name of the object itself.
[MongoDB Search nested Objects without knowing Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503339/mongodb-search-nested-objects-without-knowing-key)
[How to find specific nested objects without knowing the parent key in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347376/how-to-find-specific-nested-objects-without-knowing-the-parent-key-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understand you correctly, you can do something like this:

- Convert object `paths` into an array to can get the key value using `$objectToArray`.
- Then filter by `regex` expression the key you want. In this case `pet` is to match values where string has "pet" but you can use another regex if you want.
- After that, we will have only routes objects that matches the regex, then again convert to object using `$arrayToObject`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"swagger": "2.0"}},
  {"$set": {"paths": {"$objectToArray": "$paths"}}},
  {
    "$set": {
      "paths": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$paths",
          "as": "p",
          "cond": {"$regexMatch": {"input": "$$p.k","regex": "pet"}}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$set": {"paths": {"$arrayToObject": "$paths"}}}
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gI66quhSaOY)

Comment: Also for anyone interested (yes, almost 3 year later) this query can be executed in a single stage like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rD1SAQHhuxL). Answer query is easier "to see" but the result is the same because the point is to concatenate results into `$set` stage and not concatenate stages.